# repeat row on top of new page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

we have report with repeating headers but this time we want the top level group which contains data to repeat on top of each page.
I have set the row group properties: KeepWithGroup = After and RepeatOnNewPage = True
The tablix properties Repeat Header Rows On Each Page and Repeat Header Columns On Each Page are both checked as well.
The table header does repeat but that top level group does not.

In the image below we are trying to get the Office [Oname] row to repeat at the top of each new page.

Report Layout

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have been able to consistently make this work is to add a page number column using a modulo of the `row_number` to the source dataset, and then grouping on that.  This obviously requires that you make sure the number of data rows returned within each page number group will *always* fit on a page, which isn't always possible.

Comment: Thanks,  that got me pointed in a different direction at least.  I changed the layout on the report to remove the blank columns on the right and it actually works.  I think the issue was that when I added the grouping it added a column to the left of the report and a blank cell beside existing groups.  Had to put the new group directly above the existing groups.